# How to authenticate with GitHub using Qt and Access Token

Tags: qt, github

I try to implement GitHub authentication from my Qt application using Access Token. I can connect to GitHub using `Postman` without any problem by providing URL (in my case this is [https://api.github.com/notifications](http://api.github.com/notifications)) and access token I've generated on the GitHub (`Settings/Developer settings/Personal access tokens`) https://github.com/settings/tokens. Now I want to do the same using Qt but can't find examples how to do that. There is example for Reddit( https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetworkauth-redditclient-example.html) in the Qt documentation but it uses some redirect algorithm, not access token:

```
auto replyHandler = new QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler(1337, this);
oauth2.setReplyHandler(replyHandler);
oauth2.setAuthorizationUrl(QUrl("https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/authorize"));
oauth2.setAccessTokenUrl(QUrl("https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token"));
```

I have no clue how to do the same using provided Access Token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use the personal token then it is not necessary to implement the OAuth/OAuth2 logic since the first part of the transaction is to obtain the token but the OP already has it. If you have the token then it is only necessary to request the rest API:

```cpp
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QTimer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    const QString username = "<username>";
    const QString token = "<token>";

    const QByteArray basic_authorization = QByteArray("Basic ") + (username + ":" + token).toUtf8().toBase64();

    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setRawHeader(QByteArrayLiteral("Authorization"), basic_authorization);
    QUrl url("https://api.github.com/notifications");
    request.setUrl(url);

    QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager.get(request);
    QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [reply](){
        QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(reply->readAll());
        qDebug() << doc;
        QTimer::singleShot(1000, &QCoreApplication::quit);
    });

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @eyllanesc, that works as expected. I mistakenly assumed that I should use `QNetworkAccessManager::authenticationRequired` slot to provide credentials but that doesn't work. As notices [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/overview/other-authentication-methods#basic-authentication) Basic Authentication is supported so I will use your solution.